# Get reverbnation.com fans count with PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to get fans count from reverbnation [dot] com for an specified user? I need to get total fans count for an specified user with PHP. Somebody know how to do that?

Comment: can you provide an example page or the html structure of the relevant part of the page?

Comment: For example this page: http://www.reverbnation.com/jonathanemile
I need total fans.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use unofficial API from https://github.com/j3k0/ReverbNation-Unofficial-API